# dropdown sub menu auto width not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown menu, and I want the submenu's width to take the space it needs if the sub-menu items are big or small.

Right now, It wraps on a second line.. See

https://jsfiddle.net/nyb44xbd/1/

I tried width:auto;  doesn't work.

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
     position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 12px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    width:auto;

    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.subm{margin:12px 0;}
```

MY HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span>PRODUCT INFO</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="subm"><a class="menulink" href="#ingredients">INGREDIENTS</a></div>
        <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">CUSTOMER REVIEWS</a></div>
        <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">NUTRITIONAL FACTS</a></div>
        <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">ORDER NOW</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the `position:relative` to the body and this way the width can vary.

https://jsfiddle.net/0huz4dam/

Comment: The parent element that you have added the position relative has a fixed width based on it's content. So this way if the children had bigger text they couldn't expand more that their parent's width.

You can try adding more text to the parent and you will see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative` to the `.dropdown`. See the snippet below:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.subm {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>PRODUCT INFO</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink" href="#ingredients">INGREDIENTS</a></div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">CUSTOMER REVIEWS</a></div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">NUTRITIONAL FACTS</a></div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">ORDER NOW</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position:absolute` from the `.dropdown-content` style it will work

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 12px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.subm {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>PRODUCT INFO</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink" href="#ingredients">INGREDIENTS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">CUSTOMER REVIEWS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">NUTRITIONAL FACTS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="subm"><a class="menulink subm" href="#ingredients">ORDER NOW</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```